# Selecting all Records if Record has any of the ID's from Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, postgresql, activerecord, has-many

Good Morning Overflow.

I'm having a problem trying to select all `Treatments` that have any of the ID's stored in an array called `@problem`.

Here is my Treatments controller.

```
@problem = Remedy.find_by_sql(["SELECT id FROM remedies WHERE LOWER(\"remedyName\") LIKE?", "%#{params[:searchremedy]}%".downcase])

 query = "SELECT * FROM treatments INNER JOIN remedies_treatments on treatments.id = remedies_treatments.treatment_id WHERE remedies_treatments.treatment_id LIKE ?"
 @pretreatments = Treatment.find_by_sql([query, @problem])
```

This is error from the console

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near ","
LINE 1: ...d WHERE remedies_treatments.treatment_id LIKE 233,234,224
```

The 'LIKE' operator is probably not what I need for what I'm looking to do - I tried using the ANY operator but to no avail either. Does the problem stem from the fact it is an array of integers?

The  Treatment model.

```
class Treatment < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_and_belongs_to_many :remedy

end
```

The Remedy Model.

```
class Remedy < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_and_belongs_to_many :treatments, dependent: :destroy
end
```

There is a follow up post where my issue was resolved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37416290/select-record-if-the-records-has-same-id-as-any-of-the-ids-in-the-array/37416618#37416618)

Comment: The postgresql docs show the syntax for selecting records where an array contains any of a particular set of values.

Comment: @DavidAldridge I took a look at it already [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-comparisons.html) but it seems a bit bare on the exact syntax.

Comment: why you don't use ActiveRecord style?, and just type `Treatments.find(@problem)`. This should work if the `@problem` is an array like [1,2,3,4].

Comment: @RareFever because the ID I am comparing against is stored in a Join Table.

Comment: I am new to rails but I think this could work (somehow): `@problem = Remedy.where(remedyname: params[:searchremedy])`and `@pretreatments = Treatment.joins(:remedies).where(treatment_id: @problem)`. I recomend you to read [about joins](http://www.theodinproject.com/ruby-on-rails/active-record-queries)

Comment: @RareFever See my edit above in the original post.`@problem` should be storing the ID not `remedyName`. The following changes to your code runs, however does not return the desired result. `@problem = Remedy.find_by_sql(["SELECT id FROM remedies WHERE LOWER(\"remedyName\") LIKE?", "%#{params[:searchremedy]}%".downcase]) ` and `@pretreatments = Treatment.joins(:remedy).where(id: @problem)`.

Comment: @RareFever the console returns `SELECT "treatments".* FROM "treatments" INNER JOIN "remedies_treatments" ON "remedies_treatments"."treatment_id" = "treatments"."id" INNER JOIN "remedies" ON "remedies"."id" = "remedies_treatments"."remedy_id" WHERE "treatments"."id" IN (233, 234, 224)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selecting record by ids array is done with a query:

```
Record.where(id: ids)
```

where `ids` is ids array. It can be replaced with another query.

For your case selecting remedies by match name will be as follows:

```
ids = Remedy.where("LOWER(remedyName) LIKE ?", name.downcase).pluck(:id)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help - I am having issues with the syntax of this though because of the Join Table I am using. Could you suggest syntax in the context of my Join Table?

Comment: `class Treatment < ActiveRecord::Base has_and_belongs_to_many :remedy` `class Remedy < ActiveRecord::Base has_and_belongs_to_many :treatments` . Then there is a join table called `remedies_treatments` that stores the ID's of both Treatment and Remedy.

Comment: Thank you for your answer - however I am comparing `remedies_treatments.treatment_id` with the plucked ID. Wouldn't `Record.where(id: ids)` have a join with the Join Table?

Comment: Oh ok. Will adding a model for the Join Table create any issues or change the behavior of the application in any drastic ways?