# Select record if the records has same id as any of the ID's in the Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, has-many

I am having trouble finding the right syntax and operator to check if a record has the same ID of any of the ID's stored in an Array. Is there a `has any?` function or similar?

```
@problem = Remedy.where(["LOWER(\"remedyName\") LIKE?", "%#{params[:searchremedy]}%".downcase]).pluck(:id)

@pretreatments =  Treatment.joins(:remedies_treatment).where(:remedies_treatment_remedy_id == @problem)
```

I have updated the code to:

```
 ids = Remedy.where(["LOWER(\"remedyName\") LIKE?", "%#{params[:searchremedy]}%".downcase]).pluck(:id)

 @pretreatments = Treatment.joins(:remedies_treatments).where(remedies_treatments: { remedy_id: @problem })
```

However the error I am getting now is:

```
     SELECT "treatments".* FROM "treatments" INNER JOIN "remedies_treatments" ON "remedies_treatments"."treatment_id" = "treatments"."id" WHERE "remedies_treatment"."remedy_id" IS NULL
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 157ms (ActiveRecord: 17.0ms)

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "remedies_treatment"
LINE 1: ...atments"."treatment_id" = "treatments"."id" WHERE "remedies_...
                                                             ^
: SELECT "treatments".* FROM "treatments" INNER JOIN "remedies_treatments" ON "remedies_treatments"."treatment_id" = "treatments"."id" WHERE "remedies_treatment"."remedy_id" IS NULL):
  app/controllers/treatments_controller.rb:116:in `index'



ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "remedies_treatment"
LINE 1: ...atments"."treatment_id" = "treatments"."id" WHERE "remedies_...
                                                             ^
: SELECT "treatments".* FROM "treatments" INNER JOIN "remedies_treatments" ON "remedies_treatments"."treatment_id" = "treatments"."id" WHERE "remedies_treatment"."remedy_id" IS NULL
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:592:in `async_exec'
```

Comment: I need it to be has any though.

Comment: why don't you post the relationships between the models, looks like it can be solved with some joins

Comment: My code? It is trying to select all Treatments where the variable `remedies_treatment_remedy_id` has any one of the values stored in `@problem`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you wish to match ids, so get the list, and use it in next query:

```
ids = Remedy.where(["LOWER(\"remedyName\") LIKE?", "%#{params[:searchremedy]}%".downcase]).pluck(:id)

Treatment.joins(:remedies_treatments).where(remedies_treatments: { remedy_id: ids })
```

**NOTE**: You should have the following relation in `Treatment`:

```
class Treatment
   has_many :remedies_treatments
end
```

Comment: I thought this would work but I got this error in the console - `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "remedies_treatment"
LINE 1: ...atments"."treatment_id" = "treatments"."id" WHERE "remedies_...`

Comment: What kind of error log, I can send you the entire console error log?

Comment: Ok, the table is plural though. What does it mean by 'missing FROM-clause entry?'- Thanks for the help btw

Comment: Ok, I updated the post with the updated code and error log. Any ideas as to how to resolve the 'missing FROM-clause entry' error?

Comment: I forgot to change @problem to ids - works like a charm. Your the man, really helped me out today. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Using ActiveRecord, you can search for matching records from the database:

```
@problem = Remedy.where(["LOWER(\"remedyName\") LIKE?", "%#{params[:searchremedy]}%".downcase]).pluck(:id)
@pretreatments =  Treatment.joins(:remedies_treatment).where(:remedies_treatment_remedy_id: @problem)
```

This uses the `Hash` syntax for the `where` clause, by specifying that you want to retrieve any records where `remedies_treatment_remedy_id` includes any value in `@problem`.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write out your answer Michael. However I am not looking to return true/false or the position of a value. I am trying to return all records where the variable `remedies_treatment_remedy_id` has any of the values in the `@problem` array.

Comment: I did add the ActiveRecord search option, as well.  It was unclear whether you wanted your results from an Array, as you said, or from the database, as your example showed.  I have included both as options.